# how to find the span of 3 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

how do I find the span of 3 vectors: specifically for $(1, 1, 2)$; $(0, -1, 1)$;$(2, 5, 1)$ ?
I know the answer is $(a, b, 3a-b)$. I just don't know how you get to that answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Span means the set of vectors which can be obtained as a linear combination of the given vectors. Let $\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix} \in \text{Span} (S)$, where $S=\{(1,1,2), \, (0,-1,1), \, (2,5,1)\}$. Then
$$x\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}+y\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix}.$$
You need to find the condition on $b_1,b_2,b_3$ for which this system of equation will be consistent. For that consider the augmented matrix
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&0&2 &b_1\\
1&-1&5 &b_2\\
2&1&1&b_3
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align*}
After a row operation you will get
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&0&2 &b_1\\
0&-1&3 &b_2-b_1\\
0&1&-3&b_3-2b_1
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align*}
and then
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&0&2 &b_1\\
0&-1&3 &b_2-b_1\\
0&0&0&b_2+b_3-3b_1
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align*}
I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: I understood what you did, but how do I get to the final answer of (a,b,3a-b)?? I have a feeling it is very simple but for some reason i'm not getting it

Comment: @ArmanKh For consistency you cannot have pivot in the rightmost column. Therefore you want $b_2+b_3-3b_1=0$. This means $b_3=3b_1-b_2$. So the vectors $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ that are in the span will look like $(b_1,b_2,3b_1-b_2)$.